# QVFB not able to display the -- QT for embedded linux demo examples

Tags: linux, qt, embedded-linux

After giving sometime i am able to compile qvfb for host x11 enviroment. 
Now i am looking forward to run QT embedded linux demo program inside it. But i am not successful in this

http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/install-x11.html
Here i have configured QT source for x11 taking into refrence above link & my qvfb is lying at this location  :---
`~/qt_source/qt_source_x11/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.8.5/bin` .

http://wiki.qt.io/Building_Qt_for_Embedded_Linux
Here i have refered above link & configured & compiled QT for embedded linux host with support for LinuxFB & QVFB installed in following location :--
`/opt/Qt5.1.1/4.8.5_embedded/gcc/` .

http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qvfb.html
https://twocleverbyfull.wordpress.com/2009/09/23/qt-embedded-part-2-using-qvfb/
Now i am taking above two links into refrence & want to run qt for embedded app example in qvfb.

running qvfb for host x11 :---

```
dinesh@ubuntu:~/qt_source/qt_source_x11/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.8.5/bin$ ./qvfb
```

Now i am running books demo example :---

```
dinesh@ubuntu:/opt/Qt5.1.1/4.8.5_embedded/gcc/demos$ ls
affine        declarative         gradients   README       textedit
arthurplugin  deform              helper      shared       undo
books         demos-manifest.xml  interview   spectrum
boxes         demos.pro           mainwindow  spreadsheet
chip          embeddeddialogs     pathstroke  sqlbrowser
composition   glhypnotizer        qtdemo      sub-attaq
dinesh@ubuntu:/opt/Qt5.1.1/4.8.5_embedded/gcc/demos$ cd books/
dinesh@ubuntu:/opt/Qt5.1.1/4.8.5_embedded/gcc/demos/books$ ./books
```

Why books daemon is not going inside the qvfb ? Why It is displayed as seprate window ?

Please suggest.

Screen shot of application running :--
[image]

Comment: can any one suggest on this point... ?

Comment: have you tried `books -qws -display QVFb:0`  ?

Comment: @Mali I tried it but it did not worked. Books is opening in seprate window .... ? Why so ... what i am missing .. ?

Comment: Please any one who can suggest what i am missing here ?

Comment: I followed these links .. http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qvfb.html
http://thelins.se/learnqt/2009/06/testing-your-embedded-linux-setup-qvfb/  ... but why i am not able to display emo examples.. inside QVFB

Comment: Any suggestion on this .. i have tried everything from my end now.. but still not working.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure out the problem.

You will need two build of Qt. A normal build(using default configure settings) and an Embedded build(with -embedded,-qt-gfx-qvfb options enabled in configure).

When you have both the builds, compile the qvfb in the normal build and launch it.

In the embedded build, compile the application which you want to run in qvfb and launch the app with -qws flag.

i.e. ./myapp -qws

The app will be displayed in the qvfb.