# how to select different version of QT -- to compile project -- Linux environment

Tags: linux, qt

I am having two version of QT library installed on my PC QT5.1  which is installed by default with the QT SDK.

Other version i am having is QT-4.8.5 .

Now when ever i create new project it is build against QT-5.1 library.

How can i make it to compile against the QT-4.58.5 library.

I refered following links :--
http://qt-project.org/doc/qtcreator-2.5/creator-build-settings.html
http://doc.qt.digia.com/qtcreator/creator-project-qmake.html

```
Now even after making these changes. When i try to
```

create new project in QT creator it does not show the option to select QT-4.8.5 library.

Please suggest why so `?` What changes i have to make so that while creating project QTcreator show the option to select the QT-4.8.5 library, see section 2 of attached picture `?`

Then i made following changes manually to change the build environment of the project.
QTDIR & PATH in the project setting to QT-4.8.5 library. Please see the attached picture. Is these changes correct `?`

[image]

Comment: In second snap, under kits there will be a "Make Default" Option, by this you can switch between different compilation option.

Comment: yes its working... I have to create new entry under Manual & .. it detects the QT version i have mentioned under QT version tab...

Comment: But i am still stuck at this point now ... QT application is not displaying under QVFB.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20468282/qvfb-not-able-to-display-the-qt-for-embedded-linux-demo-examples